# Why is my code for switching elements in array not fast enough?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was supposed to write a code that shifts each element of the array a one position to left and does this operation d number of times.
For example:
if array is [1,2,3,4,5] and value of d is 2, the following should be output: [3,4,5,1,2]   (it changes with each iteration as follows: [1,2,3,4,5]==>[2,3,4,5,1]==>[3,4,5,1,2]

The problem is hackerrank times my code out in 2 of the ten test cases

I read that using for loop with range() function is much faster than using a while loop in python. So I eliminated all while loops and made the code as concise as possible. But still, the code times out when the size and quantity of numbers in the array get too big.

## This is my code( fails with big numbers):

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    for i in range(0,d):
        a=a[1:]+a[:1]
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    nd = input().split()

    n = int(nd[0])

    d = int(nd[1])

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = rotLeft(a, d)

    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

## This code is a solution I found on hackerrank(although I think it is intended to be for python 2 but that shouldn't matter):

```
def array_left_rotation(a, n, k):
    return a[k:] + a[:k]


n, k = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
answer = array_left_rotation(a, n, k);
print ' '.join(map(str,answer))
```

The solution code passes with all test inputs but my code fails when the numbers get too big and too many.

Comment: Think on how you can calculate the number of rotations beforehand and rotate only once

Answer (score 1):

Your use of a `for` loop over the `d` unnecessarily makes the solution *O(n x d)* in time complexity, where `n` is the length of `a`. You can slice the list at `d` directly instead, and to account for cases where `d` is greater than or equal to the length of `a`, you can use the remainder of `d` over the length of `a`, so that the solution would cost only *O(n)* in time complexity:

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    offset = d % len(a)
    return a[offset:] + a[:offset]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, if you need to shift `["a","b","c","d"]` 100001 times ... whats the result?

Same as shifting it 1 time. Why? Because 100000 is divisible by 4 (the length of your list) - after 4 shifts your list is back to its original - so you *can* shift if 25k times fully and once more - or simply calculate the "senseless" shifts out and shift it once.

Much faster then performing your shift inside a loop.